# Satellizer login behind facebook app

Tags: angularjs, satellizer

If i need to login in my website is behind the facebookApp in the webview of facebookApp, the popup don´t work on Iphone 6s IOS 10.1, the website doesn't login.

Is a issue or how would be solve ?

Comment: It just fail on Iphone 6s ? works properly on android?

Comment: There is a good chance that you need to provide [MCVE] for question to be answerable...